# Invalid fernet token

Tags: python, sockets, encryption

Hi I'm trying to encrypt data sent over a socket in Python (using cryptography.fernet), but whenever I run the code to send the data back, I get a cryptography.fernet.invalidtoken exception on the server end. I can decrypt the tokens with the same key locally, so I think it must be the socket. Here's the code I'm using:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
print colored("listening...","red")
s.listen(10)
conn,addr = s.accept()
print colored("connected!","red")
data = conn.recv(1024)
print data
```

Comment: It might help if you provide the exception you're seeing

Comment: Asks a question about a crypto exception, shows exactly *none* of the relevant code. I just shake my head in amazement ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry I didn't give the encryption function or exception. I was in a hurry to get this out. Anyway, I've found the solution. The issue was that the buffer defined in conn.recv() was too small and the token received was being truncated. Increasing the buffer size to a value larger than the original 1024 fixed the issue.

Comment: What you described is an incorrect and brittle method of reading data. There is no guarantee that `conn.recv(n)` will read n bytes of data, even if you sent n or more bytes. Instead you need a loop to read whatever's available until you've detected the end of the message (possibly by detecting EOF).